# What is the best way to get all linked instances of a models in Django?

Tags: sql, django, performance

I am trying to create a messaging system in Django, and I came across an issue: How could I efficiently find all messages linked in a thread?

Let's imagine I have two models:

```
class Conversation(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User)
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User)
    first_message = models.OneToOneField(Message)
    last_message = models.OneToOneField(Message)

class Message(models.Model):
    previous = models.OneToOneField(Message)
    content = models.TextField()
```

(code not tested, I'm sure it wouldn't work as is)

Since it is designed as a simple linked list, is it the only way to traverse it recursively?
Should I try to just get the previous of the previous until I find the first, or is there a way to query all of them more efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

I use Rest Framework serializer with depth. So If you have serializer with Depth value to 3. I will fetch the full model of whatever the foreign key available until three parents.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization

```
class AppliedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Applied
        fields = ("__all__")
        depth = 3
```

Comment: Accept it as an answer, If it is.